# Swift UIPanGestureRecognizer right to left only

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

I'm building a slide out menu using a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich and can't figure out how to disable left to right panning but keep right to left? I remove addLeftPanelViewController() but it still shows the pan, just not working correctly. I don't want anything to move, or unhide on the left to right.

Thanks for any help.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
            centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}



let gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight = (recognizer.velocityInView(view).x > 0)
 
switch(recognizer.state) {
  case .Began:
    if (currentState == .BothCollapsed) {
      if (gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight) {
        addLeftPanelViewController()
      } else {
        addRightPanelViewController()
      }
 
      showShadowForCenterViewController(true)
    }
  case .Changed:
    recognizer.view!.center.x = recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translationInView(view).x
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
  case .Ended:
    if (leftViewController != nil) {
      // animate the side panel open or closed based on whether the view has moved more or less than halfway
      let hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x > view.bounds.size.width
      animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway)
    } else if (rightViewController != nil) {
      let hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x < 0
      animateRightPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway)
    }
  default:
    break
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `if (gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight) return`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i'm not quite sure what you mean? I have removed addLeftPanelViewController()

Comment: Short-circuit your gesture responder and return after detecting that you're processing a gesture that you don't want to care about.

Comment: Oh I gotcha, I just tried that it still moves the controller over and shows a black background.

Answer (score 3):

try this

add Expending on the SlideOutState enum

```
enum SlideOutState {
    case BothCollapsed
    case SettingPanelExpanded
    case Expanding

}
```

then

```
switch(recognizer.state) {
        case .Began:
            if (currentState == .BothCollapsed) {
                if (gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight) {
                    addSettingPanelViewController()
                    showShadowForCenterViewController(true)
                    currentState = .Expanding
                }

            }
            if (currentState == .SettingPanelExpanded) {
                if (gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight==false) {
                    currentState = .Expanding
                }
            }
        case .Changed:
            if (currentState == .Expanding){

                println(recognizer.velocityInView(view).x)
                recognizer.view!.center.x = recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translationInView(view).x
                recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
            }
        case .Ended:
            if (settingViewController != nil) {
                // animate the side panel open or closed based on whether the view has moved more or less than halfway
                let hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x > view.bounds.size.width
                animateSettingPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did find a solution in the ray wenderlich forum. Not sure what is better but thanks for taking the time.

Comment: hi user3712837, can you share the solution(link) from ray wenderlich forum?

Comment: Here is the link to the discussion http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19064&p=79944#p79944

Comment: I needed to add the following: `if (currentState == .Expanding){
                if(recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translation(in: view).x > view.bounds.size.width/2) {
                    recognizer.view!.center.x = recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translation(in: view).x
                    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `switch` statement in an `if` condition:

```
if currentState == .LeftPanelExpanded || gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight {
  //your existing switch statement
}
```